# Invalid value when query on Int in realm

Tags: swift, int, realm

I have a realm declaration like that :

```
@objc dynamic var roomId = UUID().uuidString
@objc dynamic var roomName = ""
@objc dynamic var roomType = ""
@objc dynamic var floor = 1
@objc dynamic var placeId : String?
```

I am trying to get a query of all rooms for a specific floor in a specific place from realm DB  with this function :

```
static func getAllRoomNamesAndTypesForQuery (placeName: String? ,room : String? , floor : Int?) -> [[String]] {
    var result : [[String]] = [[]]
    if placeName != nil , floor != nil {
    let placeId = Places.specificPlaceQueries(placeName: placeName)[0] as! String
    let allRooms = Users.realm.objects(Rooms.self).filter("placeId == '\(placeId)' AND floor == '\(floor!)'")
    var roomNames = [""]
    var roomTypes = [""]
    for number in 0..<allRooms.count {
        roomNames.append(allRooms[number].roomName)
        roomTypes.append(allRooms[number].roomType)
    }

    let sortedRoomNames = roomNames.sorted()
    let sortedRoomTypes = roomTypes.sorted()

    result = [sortedRoomNames , sortedRoomTypes]
    }
    return result

}
```

but it keeps showing me the following strange error

> Expected object of type int for property 'floor' on object of type
>   'Rooms', but received: 1

I dunno how it rejects 1 as Int ?? anyone know where is the problem here??

Comment: What type is `floor!`?

Comment: i declare it like that :
@objc dynamic var floor = 1

for the query i call it with a function and floor is Int?

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve]. You should include the declaration for `Rooms` along with the declarations and input values for `placeId` and `floor`.

Comment: check the question after edit

Comment: how you declare that var **'\(floor!)'**

Comment: Why single quotes around the floor value in the predicate?

Comment: '\\(floor!)' change to \\(floor!)

Comment: `if placeName != nil , floor != nil {` should be replace with `if let` avoiding later a force unwrap.

Comment: because floor is int and you specify it in brackets as if it was string

Comment: Sh_khan : i get it from label like that  : Int(lblFloorNumber.text!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using String interpolation when creating `NSPredicate`s, since even though it is supported, it is really easy to mess up the predicate format. Simply use `%@` for substituting variable values into the predicate.

```
let allRooms = Users.realm.objects(Rooms.self).filter("placeId == %@ AND floor == %@",placeId, floor)
```

Some further improvements to your code: don't use `nil` check, then force unwrapping, use optional binding when working with Optionals.

```
if let placeName = placeName , let floor = floor {
```

Also don't add an initial value to Arrays when creating them, instead of `var roomNames = [""]` and `var roomTypes = [""]`, do

```
var roomNames = [String]()
var roomTypes = [String]()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution . It helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
let allRooms = Users.realm.objects(Rooms.self).filter { 
   $0.placeId == placeId  
   && $0.floor == floor 
}
```

Comment: That's not equivalent to Realm's filter method, since you lose the auto-updating property of Realm's `Results` instance and Swift's `filter` method also has inferior performance compared to `Realm`'s when working with `Results`.

Comment: what source you can prove it's performance isn't equivalent ?

Comment: please be specific this a link to all the documentation

Comment: I linked the full docs for a reason, it seems like you're not familiar with the Realm database framework, since using Swift's `filter` is only a valid advice when working with Realm `Object` model subclasses when the query cannot be achieved using an `NSPredicate`, which clearly isn't the case here.

Comment: However, have a look at [Differences between filtering Realm with NSPredicate and block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271459/differences-between-filtering-realm-with-nspredicate-and-block), where a Realm engineer explains the performance differences.

Answer (score 0):

First : 
set this

```
var roomNames = [""];
var roomTypes = [""];
```

to this

```
var roomNames = [String]()
var roomTypes = [String]()
```